# confusion about the lambda expression and delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Delegate is clear to understand

```
delegate int del(int i);
```

but why can we use

```
del myDelegate = x => x * x;
```

Questions here:

1. How can I assure x is int type in the lambda expresison?
2. How can I know lambda expression return a int?

Answer (score 5):

C# compiler is smart enough to implicitly figure out the type of `x` on the left side of `=>` from the context. Since it knows that you are assigning the lambda to a variable of type `del`, the compiler knows that `x` is an `int`.

As far as the return type goes, the compiler knows that `x` is an `int`, therefore the type of the `x * x` expression must also be `int`. That's how the compiler knows the return type of the lambda.

Note that the same code would not have compiled without the exact type of `myDelegate` specified:

```
// This does not compile!
var myDelegate = x => x*x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because for you to have x, you had to give it a type.  It will detect this type rather than making you tell it over and over what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're letting the compiler determine what the lamdba expression is doing.  You can sublclass using [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Actions return type is void while Func's return type is whatever you specify as the last type parameter. You can specify additional inputs in both

```
Func<in, in2, in3, output>
```

For returning an int

```
var f = new Func<int, int>(x => x*x);
```